# Extracting _sent data view from parent business unit via SQL query not returning all records

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, data-views, tracking-extract

I am trying to extract _Sent data view records in a data extension via SQL query from the parent / enterprise business unit in SFMC.

**When I am running this query** (expectation is that extracted data will include parent BU + all child BUs)

**Getting: 30millions records (expected)**

```
Select 
AccountID,
OYBAccountID,
JobID,
ListID,
BatchID,
SubscriberID,
SubscriberKey,
EventDate,
Domain,
TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
```

**When I am running this query with excluding one business unit** (expectation is that extracted data will include parent BU + all child BUs minus one child business unit)

**Getting: 8millions records (expected is 10millionos)**

```
Select 
AccountID,
OYBAccountID,
JobID,
ListID,
BatchID,
SubscriberID,
SubscriberKey,
EventDate,
Domain,
TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
OYBAccountID != 1234567
```

**In second query I am also not seeing parent BU records. My understanding is that in _Sent log, parent BU records do not have OYBAccountID field populated, is that accurate?**

**Is there any issue with my query how I am using NOT equal to? I have tried both != AND <> - same results (missing data)**

**Please advise?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want exclude specific BU, then use this SQL snippet below to accommodate Parent BU's NULL value for the OYBAccountID column.

ISNULL(OYBAccountID, 0) != 1234567